# removing \n in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, whitespace

I've got a problem with removing \n in my program here is the code

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        parent, child = line.split(",")
            parent.strip()
            child.strip()
            children[child].append(parent)
```

tried using .rstrip and other variants but it does nothing for my, this is the result i get

```
{'Patricia\n': ['Mary'], 'Lisa\n': ['Mary']}
```

the problem is when i call children["Patricia"] i get [], because it recognizes only children["Patricia\n"]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, you were quite close. Strings are immutable and hence calling `strip()` will return a new string while leaving the original one intact.

So replacing

```
parent.strip()
child.strip()
```

with

```
parent = parent.strip()
child = child.strip()
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Please use `strip` before `split`:

```
parent, child = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")
```

Issue was: `parent.strip()` needs to be re-assigned to a string as strings are immutable.

Comment: This is an acceptable solution, but perhaps you could explain why the OP's original code didn't work, even though it also calls strip.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in explanation. `parent.strip()` needs to be re-assigned to a string. Hence, you could not see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `strip()` on its own does not change the original value. You will either need to assign to a variable first or use it within your dictionary creation.

Do see if the following snippet solves you problem

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        parent, child = line.split(",")
            children[child.strip()].append(parent.strip())
```